# Using mapview and colouring all the labels a different colour depending on the genus they are in

Tags: colors, mapview

I am making a map in R using mapview. I want to be able to change the colours of the points so that each Genus has its own colour as opposed to them all being the same. How can I do this?

My code is here:

mapview(Stegosauridae, xcol = "Longitude", ycol = "Latitude", crs = 4269, grid = FALSE, label=Stegosauridae$Genus)

I have 10 genera and want them all to be a different colour.

I tried adding the line:  col = factor(Stegosauridae$Genus), but got the error: Error in .local(x, ...) : argument 6 matches multiple formal arguments

I was also suggested doing a palette but was given no indication on how to do that.